# How to make orbit of a planet by using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, physics

I have already written the code for the general equation of orbit for `'r'(Radius)` value, and trying to plot graph for `x=r*cos(theta)` and  `y=r*sin(theta)` but my code giving me the same value of 'x' for different value of 'r'.So i'm ending`enter code here` up with a straight line instead of an ellipse.

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pprint

L = 9.11*10**38     #L = angular momentum
m = 3.28*10**23     #m = mass of mercury
M = 1.99*10**30     #M = mass of sun
a = 5.8*10**7       #a = semi-major axis
G = 6.674*10**-11   #G = Gravitationl constant
k = G*M*m        
E = -k/(2*a)        #E = energy
p = L**2/(m*k)   
c = 1 + (2*E*L**2)/m*k**2
e = sqrt(-c)        #e = eccentricity

def fx(x):
    r = p/(1 + e*cos(x))
    return r

n = 1000
phi =linspace(0,2*pi,n)
radius = zeros([n])
theta = zeros([n])
x = zeros([n])
y = zeros([n])

for i in range(0,n):
    radius[i] = fx(phi[i])
    theta[i] = 180*phi[i]/pi

for i in range(0,n):
    x[i] = radius[i]*cos(phi[i])

for i in range(0,n):
    y[i] = radius[i]*sin(phi[i])

print('r =',radius)
print('x =',x)
print('y =',y)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Here is a screenshot of my maths book:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a mimimum working example of your code

Comment: sorry of that, actually that time i was editing the question.please help me out

Comment: @johnO help me out ASAP.

Comment: The problem is with your `fx`. It returns values which are virtually zero. Check your units (which is where I suspect that the problem lies). Note that `e` doesn't make sense as a planet eccentricity. It is `6.005333658899551e+88` It is that number (since it appears in the denominator) which gives you `fx` values which are indistinguishable from zero.

Comment: I think there are some more problems in the code because even if I fix it I don't get a correct plot, but the line where you define c is wrong.
You have `1 + (2*E*L**2)/m*k**2` which means that the k**2 lands in the numerator. Change it to `1 + (2*E*L**2)/(m*k**2)`

But even after the fix, I'm still getting an eccentricity of 31.629 which is way too high.

Comment: With the fix suggested by @JohnO you still have `e = 31.6296` but if you are trying to model Mercury's orbit you should have `e = 0.2056`

Comment: thanx @johnO for helping

Comment: thanx @johnColeman for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are (at least) two problems with your code:

1) `a = 5.8*10**7` should be `a = 5.8*10**10` since (given your `G`) you need that distance in meters rather then kilometers.

2) As pointed out by @JohnO, you need `1 + (2*E*L**2)/(m*k**2)` rather than `1 + (2*E*L**2)/m*k**2`

If you make these two changes, you get a reasonable ellipse:

[image]